# Can every group action be represented as a conjugation by unitaries?

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a countable discrete group, and $l^\infty(G) := \{f \colon G \to \mathbb{C} \mid \|f\|_\infty < \infty\}$.
Let a group action of $s \in G$ on $f \in l^\infty(G)$ be defined as $(s \mathbin{.} f)(g) = f(s^{-1}g)$ for all $g ∈ G$.

Is it then true that for every $s \in G$ there exists a $u_s \in B(l^2(G))$ such that (and $l^\infty(G)\subseteq B(l^2(G))$
$$
  s \mathbin{.} f = u_s f u_s^* \,?
$$

I somehow have a feeling that this should be true since it is (apparently) stated in *$C^∗$-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations* by Brown and Ozawa (page 54).

Comment: is $s.f$ as defined above a left translation action?

Comment: What would be a left action on $l^\infty (G)$?
probably my intuition doesn't go hand in hand with how I think a left translation action is (my feeling, I agree, aren't so relevant) :)

Comment: In a text I'm reading, the author states that a left translation action can be realised as $u_s f u_s^*$. I could only assume that a left action would mean $s.f(g)=f(s^{-1}g)$.
Does it mean something else? 
(hope it makes some sense now)

Comment: Thank you for the clear up.
it comes from $C^*\textit{-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations}$
by Brown and Ozawa (page 54) in case you are wondering :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that here we consider $l^\infty(G)\subseteq B(l^2(G))$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It is not weird at all: $\ell^\infty$ is a $C^*$-algebra, and there is a well-defined notion of unitary in such a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $$\ell^\infty(G)\subseteq B(\ell^2(G))$$ means the embedding $f\mapsto M_f,$ where $M_f$ stands for the multiplication operator on $\ell^2(G)$.

---

For $s\in G$ and $\phi\in \ell^2(G)$, we define the operator $u_s$ by $$u_s \phi = s \mathbin{.} \phi.$$ Clearly, $u_s$ is an unitary operator on $\ell^2(G)$ and $u_s^*=u_{s^{-1}}$. It is routine to check that $u_s$ does the job.

By the boundedness, it is enough to check $$u_s M_f u_s^*=M_{s\mathbin{.} f}$$ on some orthonormal basis. Let $\{e_t: t\in G\}$ be the canonic orthonormal basis of $\ell^2(G)$, easily computation shows
\begin{align}u_s M_f u_s^* \,e_t&=u_sM_f\,e_{s^{-1}\,t}=u_sf(s^{-1}t)\,e_{s^{-1}\,t}\\ 
&=f(s^{-1}t)u_s \,e_{s^{-1}\,t}=f(s^{-1}t)\,e_t\\
&=M_{s\mathbin{.} f} \,e_t.
\end{align}